# How does Xuggler's IPacket corresponds with FLV tags or tag part?

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg, flv, xuggle

FLV format specification is here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flv/pdfs/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

1) FLV body consists of tags

2) Each tag consists of header and data

3) Data may be `AUDIODATA` or `VIDEODATA`

4) `AUDIODATA` consists of descriptor byte and audio frames.

My question is: what is in `IPacket` when reading FLV with Xuggler?

Currently I do extract audio frames from `AUDIODATA` in my code. I analyze first byte, deduce format, cut other data, wrap it into `IPacket` and send it to `IStreamCoder` decoder, which was set up with deduced format.

But may be I can entrust this to Xuggler? May be I can create `IContainer` of FLV format and peek packets from it?

Suppose I pass `InputStream` to `IContainer`. Can this stream contain just FLV body? Will it extract audio packets correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IContainer object in Xuggler will parse the FLV stream and use it to determine the IStream's in the container.  Then as you read each packet from the IContainer, check the IPacket#getStreamIndex() value.  This gives you the stream #, which you can then use on the IContainer to get the IStream object with the meta-data.

The IPacket#getData() method will return the payload of the audio, but not any of the header bytes.  That is because the IContainer/IStream object eats those bytes (and they are not accessible independently through Xuggler).

All of this works because IContainer delegates to FFmpeg's libavformat C-code which does the job of parsing FLV streams (used by VLC, mPlayer, and all sorts of other libraries).

Hope that helps,

Art

Comment: If I use `IPacket#getStreamIndex()` may I avoid using `IContainer#getStream() + IStream#getStreamCoder()` and just create `IStreamCoder` independently with it's `make()` method?

Comment: now; you'll need to get the one from the IContainer since it's actually the IContainer that manages the meta-data.

Comment: What for to check stream number of the packet then? When I am taking coder from the container, I am obliged to specify this number already. Am I correct? Or this is some other stream number?

Comment: See com.xuggle.xuggler.Converter for code that does what you're talking about.  It first queries the IContainer for the number of streams, and then gets each IStream.